# hyper-v any way to automatically start a vm after merge?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

In Hyper-V, a VM needs to be shutdown for the merging of deleted snapshots to take place. The merge process can take a long time so I wanted to know if there is any available method/program/script to monitor the merge process and restart the VM once the merge is completed?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to merge snapshots frequently, seriously consider upgrading to Server 2012, where [Hyper-V is capable of live merging deleted snapshots](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/photostory/2240148778/Top-five-Hyper-V-30-features-that-will-excite-IT-pros/5/Five-best-Hyper-V-30-features-Live-merging-of-VM-snapshots) (you would not need to shut down the VM using the VHD/AVHD any more).

With Server 2008(R2), you surely could Powershell to your liking using a variation of

```
gwmi -Namespace root\virtualization -query "select * from Msvm_ConcreteJob" | Where {$_.ElementName -eq 'Merge in Progress'}
```

to check on the merge process you are interested in and start the VM subsequently using [`Start-VM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848589.aspx).